# Asymptotics for $f(\lambda)=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(\lambda+1)^x}dx$ as $\lambda\to0^+$.

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals

I would like to find asymptotics, as $\lambda\to0^+$ ($\lambda$ is a positive parameter), for

$$
f(\lambda)=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(\lambda+1)^x}dx.
$$

There is uniform convergence to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ of the integrand, as $\lambda\to0^+$, and hence $f(\lambda)\to+\infty$, as $\lambda\to0$, but I would like to find the "velocity" of this divergence. Are there any simple estimates that would lead to the asymptotics that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $u=\sqrt x$ so \begin{align}f(\lambda)&=2\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{(\lambda+1)^{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac\pi{\log(\lambda+1)}}\left(1-\operatorname{erf}\sqrt{\log(\lambda+1)}\right)\end{align} where the last equality is reached by recognising that $(\lambda+1)^{-x^2}$ is akin to a Gaussian density. A Taylor series expansion gives $$f(\lambda)=\sqrt{\frac\pi{\log(\lambda+1)}}-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\log^n(\lambda+1)}{n!(2n+1)}=\sqrt{\frac\pi\lambda}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\lambda^n$$ for some real $a_n$. Thus $f$ diverges at a rate of $\mathcal O(\lambda^{-1/2})$ as $\lambda\to0^+$.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Could you maybe elaborate a bit more about the second display? What function did you expand? And are the equalities in the second display actual equalities or they are to be intended as "asymptotic to as $\lambda\to0^+$?

Comment: They are all equalities. In the second display I simply used the Maclaurin expansion for $\operatorname{erf}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think this approach (to find asymptotics as $\lambda\to0^+$) could work in a more general framework like $f(\lambda)=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^{\frac{a}{2}}(\lambda+1)^x}dx$ for an integer $a$, $a\geq1$? I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Yes. It's more complicated as the integral will involve incomplete gamma functions (this is because the lower limit is nonzero).

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(\lambda+1)^x}\,dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-\ln(\lambda+1)x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$
now try using the substitution $u^2=x\Rightarrow dx=2u\,du$ and so:
$$2\int_1^\infty e^{-\ln(\lambda+1)u^2}\,du$$
now letting $v=\sqrt{\ln(\lambda+1)}u\Rightarrow du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(\lambda+1)}}dv$ which gives us:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\ln(\lambda+1)}}\int\limits_{[\ln(\lambda+1)]^{1/2}}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,du=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln(\lambda+1)}}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\ln(\lambda+1)}\right)$$
now as $\lambda\to0^+,\sqrt{\ln(\lambda+1)}\to0$ and so $\operatorname{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\ln(\lambda+1)}\right)\to1^-$. This means that the rate of divergence of this integral will just be:
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln(\lambda+1)}}\,\,\,\,,\lambda\to0^+$$